# 2 functions onSubmit event , only either of them works. Both - dont (((

Tags: javascript, function, onsubmit

So I have been trying to create a form that adds information to the table AFTER this information is validated (table is being inserted dynamically) . So I have 2 main functions that are both being invoked when submit button is clicked. BUT ! Unfortunately only one of them works at the time,what I mean is if I write onsubmit="validateForm()" it works. If I write onsubmit="myFunction()" it works ! But if I use onsubmit="vaidateForm() && myfunction()"neither of them work. Please help me get the validation and the insert table functions to both work.

Im nearly done with validation functions

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/    css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="    sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7    " crossorigin="anonymous">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/    css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/    M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body onload="document.info.firstName.focus();">

<div class="container">

    <form onsubmit="return validateForm() && myFunction(event)" id="info" name="    info">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="    firstName" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="    lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Phone" name="    phone" placeholder="Phone">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Gender" name="    gender" placeholder="Gender">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="age">Age</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Age" name="age"     placeholder="Age">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
    </form>


    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <br>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validatefirstName(info) {
        var u = document.forms.info.firstName.value
        var uLength = u.length;
        var illegalChars = /\W/; // allow letters, numbers, and underscores
        if (u == null || u == "") {
            alert("You left First Name field empty");
            return false;
        } else if (uLength < 4 || uLength > 11) {
            alert("Last Name must be between 4 and 11 characters");
            return fasle;
        } else if (illegalChars.test(u)) {
            alert("First Name contains illegal characters");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function validatelastName(info) {
        var u = document.forms.info.lastName.value
        var uLength = u.length;
        var illegalChars = /\W/; // allow letters, numbers, and underscores
        if (u == null || u == "") {
            alert("You left Last Name field empty");
            return false;
        } else if (uLength < 4 || uLength > 11) {
            alert("Last Name must be between 4 and 11 characters");
            return fasle;
        } else if (illegalChars.test(u)) {
            alert("Last Name contains illegal characters");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function allnumeric(info) {
        var n = document.forms.info.phone.value
        var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if (n.match(numbers)) {
            alert('Cheers');
            n.focus();
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Please input numeric characters only');
            n.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function age(info) {
        var n = document.forms.info.age.value
        var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if (n.match(numbers)) {
            alert('Cheers');
            n.focus();
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Please input numeric characters only');
            n.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }


    function validateForm() {

        if (validatefirstName() && lastName() && allnumeric() && age()) return     true;
        else return false;

    }

    function myFunction(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var form = document.forms.info;
        var fName = form.elements.firstName.value;
        var lName = form.elements.lastName.value;
        var phone = form.elements.phone.value;
        var gender = form.elements.gender.value;
        var age = form.elements.age.value;


        //add table rows
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow();
        var cell0 = row.insertCell();
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell1.innerHTML = fName;
        cell2.innerHTML = lName;
        cell3.innerHTML = phone;
        cell4.innerHTML = gender;
        cell5.innerHTML = age;

        //clear table rows
        document.getElementById("info").reset();

        //create button that deletes table rows
        var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        button.id = "redButton";
        button.innerHTML = "X";
        cell6.appendChild(button);
        button.onclick = function () {

            this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.    parentNode);
        }


    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are a multitude of issues here. the whole script needs to be looked at, refactured and the inline event handlers moved to proper event handlers in the head. Also the preventDefault seems to be used to stop submission. Do you want to submit or not?

Comment: Note that whenever you find yourself writing `if (condition) return true; else return false;`, simply `return condition;` is usually a better option. If it's important to ensure that you're returning `true` and `false` *specifically* (not just truthy or falsy values), you might use double-bang: `return !!condition;`.

Answer (score 1):

If the left-hand side of `&&` returns a falsy value, the right-hand is never evaluated at all, because `&&` short-circuits: Once it knows its result will be falsy, it returns that value without evaluating the right-hand side.

If you want both functions to always run, then you can't use `&&`. While you *could* do what [Thinker suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37644305/157247) and use `&`, I would advise **not** doing that, it sets you up for a maintenance problem later when you think (or someone else thinks) that it's a typo. Instead, I'd define a new function:

```
function doBothOfThem(event) {
    // Note: Important that we always call both functions
    var r1 = validateForm();
    var r2 = myFunction(event);
    return r1 && r2;
}
```

...and then use that.

Comment: But, && doesn't evaluate the right-hand operand if the left-hand operand is false

Comment: @Thinker: Yes, I said that in the first paragraph after the first code block: *"and so the left-hand operand to `&&` is never truthy and so the right-hand is never evaluated at all"*

Comment: @Thinker: The bigger problem with the original answer above (now fixed!) is that `validateForm` **does** return `true`! I just didn't see it, as it was so far off to the right. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much ! I applied the first version of you answer and it helped, now I will try the new one.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a typo in first function "fasle" instead of "false".
2. You're also using lastName() instead of validatelastName().
3. document.forms.info.phone.value  don't exists because the id is
   "Phone" and the name is "    phone" (with the space).
4. In allnumeric() and age(), you are trying to use .focus() on the string .value instead of the HTML element.

Comment: These are all very useful points, but none of them is an *answer* to the question. The answer box is just for answers; really useful things like your observations above go in *comments* instead.

Comment: if you fix these errors, the code in the onsubmit works because it's already correct. The question I've read is "why does the validation process don't work" and the answer is, because there is errors (bad function name, variable that don't exists, ...), using function on the wrong variables.

Comment: @progysm: No, the code in the `onsubmit` doesn't work, because the OP's issue is that the second function isn't run if the first returns a falsy value, because `&&` short-circuits. But he/she wants *both* functions to run, even if the end result will be falsy. Again, these are very useful points, but they don't address the central issue detailed in the question.

Comment: The answer about "&"  and answer describing function joining 2 functions helped a lot AND yes progysm you are right there are errors. Im fixing them now, the new question is how do I see my own mistakes the way you see them )

Comment: I've copied that code in a jsfiddle and the onsubmit works when you fix these errors.

Comment: @AlexHermann: Questions on SO aren't meant to be moving targets. You asked specifically about only one of the functions running. That's been answered. If, after trying to resolve the other issues (using the debugger built into your browser, etc.) you still have an issue, post a new question specific to that issue.

Comment: @progysm: **Again:** If `validateForm` returns a falsy value, `myFunction` doesn't get run at all. The OP quite clearly asked about that specific issue.

Comment: T.J. Crowder my question was answered and Im very grateful for that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z0ur3abh/  - some fixes (maybe there is others). Also Alex, I'm just checking ther error reported in the native browser console.

Comment: progysm, thank you so much for you help, this means a lot to me , this a test task for my first job (I hope). When I test the code you provided in the jsfiddle it works fine, but when I copy it to sublime text something is wrong with the table rows. But let me doublecheck.